# wix: does INSTALLDIR always end in a slash?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I think the default dir gets a trailing slash.

But what if the user selects a different directory?

Is there a way for the INSTALLDIR to NOT have a trailing slash?

It's not that I want it to not have a trailing slash. I want to know if I can count on it, so that, for example,

```
[INSTALLDIR]Filter.dll
```

...will always resolve to a real, valid filesystem path.

Currently I use

```
[INSTALLDIR]\Filter.dll
```

and I get a double-slash in there.  It's valid and resolves, but I'd like to eliminate the double slash.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Instaler directory table entries ( which become properties after costing ) are always formatted by MSI to contain a trailing backslash.    Including extra slashes will not harm the resolution.

Comment: Thanks. Does "after costing" imply "after the user may have selected a different install directory"?

Comment: Costing is performed from CostInitialize to CostFinalize.  The directory table entries are available after the CostFinalize action.  If the INSTALLDIR is then changed using a Type 35 Directory Custom Action or ControlEvent ( Browse Button )  it will be recosted and reformatted for the new value.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that Windows Installer will add a backslash to any Directory table entry.  Therefore, yes, you can eliminate your slash and not worry about things breaking.

In fact, this has even prompted InstallShield to create a KB article describing how to REMOVE the backslash...

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q106587